# A class 3 group of order 243

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups, classification

Let G be a group of order $243=3^5$. We denote by $(G_i)$ its lower central series and assume that $G$ has class $3$ and that $|G:G_2|=|G_3|=9$. We assume moreover that the cubing map factors as a (well-defined) bijection $G/G_2\rightarrow G_3$.
One can show that such group $G$ exists and that it is unique up to isomorphism.

Does this group already have a name?

Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't call it a special groups, because special groups have class $2$ by definition.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know people used that terminology, I will keep it in mind in the future!

Comment: I think it is not polite to silently change your question.

Comment: I am sorry, I wanted to reply to your comment and it disappeared. Thank you very much, I made a typo. It cannot exist one of order 729 because $G_3$ is the surjective image of $G/G_2\otimes G_2/G_3$, which has order 9.

Comment: In any case I think it extremely unlikely that this particular group has a name.

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong, but GAP shows there are seven groups with the above property. Their id's are [ 243, 3 ], [ 243, 4 ], [ 243, 5 ], [ 243, 6 ], [ 243, 7 ], [ 243, 8 ], 
  [ 243, 9 ] .

Comment: By my calculation, only the group [243,9] has the desired properties. For the other groups of order 243 with derived subgroup of order 27 and nilpotence class 3, the image of the cubing map has size less than 9, so it does not define a bijection, as required.

Comment: My bad, I found an error in my calculation, [243,9] is indeed the only one. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: There are many more examples in $p$-groups with $p>2$, $8$ groups for $p=5$ and $10$ groups for $p=7$. So the uniqueness for $p=3$ seems to be just an accident as $3$ is a small prime.