# Is $[729,57]$ a Sylow $3$-subgroup of some well-known group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $G$ be the group $[729,57]$, using GAP's notation. I have so far two descriptions of the group:

- a presentation
- an embedding (not surjective!) of the group into a Sylow $3$-subgroup of the unit group of a finite ring

Is $G$ isomorphic to a Sylow $3$-subgroup of some well-known group?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: How did you come upon this particular group originally?

Comment: I am studying a particular type of automorphisms of finite p-groups. More precisely, I want to classify, for p an odd prime, all finite p-groups that have an automorphism of order 2 sending each subgroup to a conjugate. The case of 3-groups is special and [729,57] gives a (unique up to isomorphism) maximal class example. As it will be one of the shining stars in my PhD thesis, I wanted to give it some extra context.

Comment: Interesting. I just checked with GAP that the normalizer of a Sylow $3$-subgroup $P$ in $3.J_3$ has the form $C_8 P$, and your automorphism is realized by conjugation with any of the involutions in this Sylow normalizer. Moreover, any such involution generates the center of a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $3.J_3$.

Comment: Wow thanks! I asked a question some months ago (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/211598/a-class-3-group-of-order-243) concerning the group [243,9], which now turns out to be a 3-Sylow of J3. I *believe* at this point that these involutions have something to do with the 3-Sylows of 3.J3 being isomorphic to [729,57]. The reason why I say this is that [243,9] has at least another extension (namely [729,56]) which however does not have an automorphism of order 2 sending each subgroup to a conjugate. I however still need to work out if all of this makes sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes (to my surprise) it appears to be isomorphic to the Sylow $3$-subgroup of $3.J_3$, the $3$-fold cover of the Janko sporadic simple group $J_3$. Here is some Magma code:

```
> C:=MatrixGroup("3J3",1);
> P:=Sylow(C,3);   
> IdentifyGroup(P);  
<729, 57>
```

And here is GAP code for the same computation (thanks to  Stefan Kohl and Frieder Ladisch)

```
LoadPackage("AtlasRep");;
G:=AtlasGroup("3.J3");;
v:= Z(4)^0*[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0];;
Gperm:= Action( G, Orbit( G, v, OnRight), OnRight );;
P := SylowSubgroup(Gperm,3);;
IdGroup(P);
```

[ 729, 57 ]

Comment: Many thanks, both for the answer and the code!

Comment: The definition of $3.J_3$ as a subgroup of ${\rm GL}(9,4)$ is coming from the online ATLAS database of Robert Wilson et al. I tried to do this in GAP. The package AtlasRep loaded OK, but G := AtlasGroup("3J3"); returned fail.The documentation says something about it getting the data over the internet, but this didn't work for me.

Comment: @Derek: You just omitted a dot -- `G := AtlasGroup("3.J3");` works (at least for me!).

Comment: Ah right, thanks! In fact I had got the group generators from the online ATLAS webpage, but I am struggling to compute the Sylow $3$-subgroup. I have tried using ProjectiveActionHomomorphismMatrixGroup and I have got the Sylow $3$-subgroup of the image, which has order $3^5$, but now I am having difficulty getting the inverse image of this.

Comment: Computing the Sylow subgroup directly from the matrix group in GAP seems to take loooooong (too long for my patience). But one can first convert the group to a permutation group: do `v:= [1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0];` and `Gperm:= Action( G, Orbit( G, v, OnRight), OnRight );` (a permutation group on $61560$ points), then `s:= SylowSubgroup( Gperm, 3 );` returns a Sylow $3$-subgroup in a few seconds. It seems that Magma is more clever in this situation?

Comment: I am extremely grateful, thank you all very much for helping me out.